# Swift In App Purchase to increase a UserDefault value isn't been refreshed until app reload

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

The user has the option to purchase "coins" which can then be used to purchase a different type of vehicle to be used during game play.

This is the code for the in app purchase of coins:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Purchased")

            let oldCoin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
            let newCoin = oldCoin + 500

            UserDefaults.standard.set(newCoin, forKey: "COINSCORE")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            coinLabel.removeFromParent()                
            createCoinScore()

            // apply purchased here and store info in userDefaults
        case .failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Failed")
        default:
            break

        }
    }
}
```

This purchase is working perfectly and the coinScore will increase once purchase is complete.

The problem is that when the coinScore is sufficient enough for the player to then purchase a vehicle it doesn't seem register the increased coinScore until after the view is loaded by either re loading the app or changing scenes and returning.

The coinScore is added as a variable as so:

```
    var coinScore = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
```

This is the code which allows the player to purchase a vehicle:

```
 if(atPoint(location) == greyship2){

            if coinScore > 20 {
                let oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
                let newValue = oldValue - 20

                UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "COINSCORE")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ship2")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                coinLabel.removeFromParent()
                coinImage1.removeFromParent()
                coinLabel1.removeFromParent()

                createCoinScore()



                greyship2.setScale(0)
                greyship2.removeFromParent()

                let ship2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship2.png")
                ship2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: ship2Texture)
                ship2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY)
                ship2.setScale(1)
                self.addChild(ship2)
                break //finish the touchesbegan call
            }
```

After purchase, although the coinScore value shown in the view does update immediately the user cannot then click greyShip2 to purchase it until the app has been refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glad you found the solution. I would just like to suggest a better way of reading and writing to UserDefaults.

```
    var <anyVariableName>: String!{
get {
    var value = ""
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey( UserDefaultsKey.USER_ID_STORED) != nil {
        value = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey( UserDefaultsKey.USER_ID_STORED)  as! String
    }
    return value
}

set(value) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.USER_ID_STORED)
}

}
```

This saves you the trouble of creating instances of UserDefaults each time you read and write to it.You can now directly access this variable to read and write to it.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem.

It seems the coinScore variable wasn't updating straight away.

What I've done is change:

```
if coinScore > 20 {
```

to

```
if UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "COINSCORE") > 20 {
```

Hopefully someone can expand on my answer.